# tableView shows duplicate values

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a search bar where I search for users. When I first search for a user, it displays the correct result. But when I move to the detailed view (to the user's profile), tap any button there, and move back, the value triplicates. It doesn't affect the result when I move, don't tap on any button, and move back. Here are the code snippets that I use:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search people (by username)"
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

    requestManager.delegate = self
}

func updateSearchResults(_ sender: RequestManager) {
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        requestManager.resetSearch()
        requestManager.searchUser(validatedText)
        print("Validated text: \(validatedText)")
}

func searchUser(_ searchText: String) {
        refUsers.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            let snapshotDictionary: [String: AnyObject] = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

            for (userKey, _) in snapshotDictionary {

                if let usernameValue = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: userKey).childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value as? String
                {
                    if usernameValue.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                        let userData = JSON(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: userKey).value!)


                        self.searchUsers.append(userData)
                    }

                    if self.delegate != nil {
                        self.delegate?.updateSearchResults(self)
                    }

                }
                else {
                    print("Users could not be found.")
                }

            }

        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

}
```

What seems to be calling the result thrice when I move back from the detail view? None of the functions here are in the detail view.

Comment: The problem is not your tableview, but your searchUsers. You are calling append every time and not flushing old results

Answer (score 4):

Simply remove objects from the array before adding more.

```
 self.searchUsers.removeAll()
self.searchUsers.append(userData)
```

So just add that piece of code and you will be good to go.

Comment: but with this at a time only one data is stored suppose i have 3 users and i want display all of them is tableview then what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in your same initiliazed array you are appending the data. So try in this way Whenever you tapped on button re-initiliazed your array or check the duplicate entry inside your array and accordingly append the data. Either approach you can follow.

Comment: I'm trying to clear the data with `self.searchUsers.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)` the first thing in the searchUser() method but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try bellow like . On search

```
 //Original array
 var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
//Search Array
 var searchArrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
var searching:Bool = false

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchArrRes = self.arrRes.filter({(($0["branchName"] as! String).localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText))})


    if(searchArrRes.count == 0){
        searching = false
    }else{
        searching = true
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData();
}
```

Just like give the condition to table view method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if( searching == true){
        return searchArrRes.count
    }else{
        return arrRes.count
    }

}
```

Set value to table cell like bellow

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:BranchLocationCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomCell

    if( searching == true){
        cell.tv_branch_name.text = searchArrRes[indexPath.row]["branchName"] as! String

    }else{
        cell.tv_branch_name.text = arrRes[indexPath.row]["branchName"] as! String
               }


    return cell;
}
```